# Untrusted Enterprise Developer (With No Profile viewable To Trust)

Tags: ios

We have been an Enterprise Developer for a client of mine for many years.  We have approximately 15 different apps that we push out through our MDM.  These apps were updated for IOS 13 a few months back.
The apps are distributed to many (about 300) remote iPads.

The apps all worked fine on everyone's iPads (Ipads are running ios13) 
This morning suddenly when you try to open any of the apps you get a prompt about the "Untrusted Enterprise Developer".. When we go to Settings, General, Profile 7 Device management there is NO profile showing that we can trust?

Again the apps worked fine however now everyone is unable to use any of the apps.. any ideas on how to correct?

Comment: Your certificate revoked by Apple.

Comment: When was the last time you renewed your signing certificate and/or provisioning profiles and distributed new versions of the apps?